# Using P104-100 GPU on Ubuntu (as single or second GPU)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, gpu

**What I have:**

GA-B250-Fintech motherboard

Ubuntu 18.04 (but I'm ready to reinstall to any version if it will work)

```
$ uname -r
4.18.0-18-generic
```

And P104-100 video card.

```
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [P104-100] (rev a1)

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-9ubuntu1~18.04.york0) 7.4.0
```

### I tried to install different nvidia drivers: 390, 410, 418, 430. Still doesn't works. I suppose it's about motherboard/BIOS setup or xconf file.

**The problem:**
every time I install nvidia drivers, Ubuntu stop loading. Usually with message:

> started user manager uid 121.

I plug out P104-100 and plug in GTX 1060, this works correctly:

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Mon May 13 22:56:17 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.74       Driver Version: 418.74       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   42C    P8     6W / 120W |      0MiB /  6078MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then I tried plug in P104-100 as second card using another slot, and Ubuntu stops loading: freeze with message

> Started GNOME Display Manager.

Sometime it can be

> Started Disk Driver

or smth else (so looks like it is not the real error message).

P.S. Using `lshw -C display` I found both cards have
physical id: 0
Can it be a reason?

---

**Question:**
How to install both cards on Ubuntu?
I think if I successfully install P104-100 as single card the same solution could be for installing both of them.

---

P.S. I found some solution about editing xconf for using on multiple GPUs: [for example.](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1003017/how-do-i-set-one-gpu-for-display-and-the-other-two-gpus-for-cuda-computing-/)
But it did not help.

I also had problem to connect second monitor - solved it by changing BIOS parameters. So I tried the same for P104 - turn on/off all the parameters in BIOS but every time Ubuntu freezes.

Comment: have you tried it on ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: @BudgetTech Hi! Yes, I have tried 19.04 because it has preinstalled driver (418 as I remember). So it's loading to ubuntu without errors, but still doesn't see P104 GPU: nvidia-smi find only 1060.

Comment: @Fabby added info. Thank you for your help!

Comment: YW. Redundant comments deleted.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try 16.04 with a trick? If you just ned to get inro os with that card in, this may work.

I had 2 p106-100 cards one was never working, but other was. Heres my story

1. Remove the gpu from the pc start the 16.04 installer update the software updater, but decline the update to 18.
2. Turn off the pc put in the card. It will be noisier at boot this is normal. Once the pc is booted itll slow the  to normal in a minute or two.
3. Do NOT swap to nvidia driver or it wil give a weird error before you can even get  the os afte the splash. But point is youre in the os. My bad p106 booted in primary slot this way. But no games on xorg driver.